# Beamer - best way to manage "show notes on second screen" on MacOS in 2019

Tags: beamer

I just compiled my slides for the first time with the option "show notes on second screen". It produces, as all of you know, PDF slides which contain the part of the notes and the content of the presentation.

I've found a few topics of how to display those files in a right way. But, all of the topics were a little old. So, I decided to ask you again, how to do this in 2019 and especially on MacOS.

Thanks a lot for your help and for sharing your experience!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Présentation.app](http://iihm.imag.fr/blanch/software/osx-presentation/) was just updated a few weeks ago to include support for beamer's notes on second screen (they appear below the current slide in the presenter view).